# Which is most used? RSS or Atom? and which one is better to build from?

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

I am thinking of using either RSS or Atom in my project, but also "enhancing" the feed with some of my own special attributes specifically used by my project.

So I have two questions:

1) Which is most used of RSS and Atom on the web and by the big sites?

2) Which is most suitable to be build from by adding my own tags?

Update:

> *So RSS is most used, but I should pick Atom since I need to make my own tweaks on a feed? If RSS is more popular, why not pick that? Why didn't Google pick that?*

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't care if big names use it or not. You should care about how many feed readers can actually handle Atom (I think, almost any half decent feed reader)

Comment: The most direct answer about popularity [is here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10416/116364). See also near duplicate at [SoftwareEngineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/57814/316529) to which everyone replies: It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There was a day when I was *really* interested in syndication and publishing formats. I knew all the quirks of RSS 0.91/1.0/2.0 and Atom 1.0 (and the 0.3 version). Atom was basically born to create something more complete out of the RSS experience which consisted roughly only on the very specifications of Dave Winer's and Netscape's (now only the RSS 2.0 makes practical sense and its specification is here: http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html). Atom was started by Sam Ruby, then was adopted and developed by a committee of savvy people and it resulted in two things: an XML based syndication format and a publishing protocol. Since 2005 Atom is an IETF standard and in my opinion more complete and better specified than RSS.

As of adoption I think that in raw numbers RSS is still in advantage. A lot of sites decided to stick with the version they already had in place (RSS) and podcasting is usually done on RSS too. There a ton of websites offering both by the way.

As of expanding the format, your second question, Atom has been created with this in mind so you should go down that route. Google GData format is basically an extension of the Atom format: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/1.0/elements

Comment: So RSS is most used, but I should pick Atom since I need to make my own tweaks on a feed? If RSS is more popular, why not pick that? Why didn't Google pick that?

Comment: @corgrath: the GData format is actually based on both to be honest, they chose to develop the API upon Atom publishing protocol because there is no RSS publishing protocol I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Atom is absolutely the standard to go for.

I presume you're using the standard to share (or move) information - so it's like a pipe that your information is padding along.   By adopting Atom you can be confident that both ends of the pipe are in agreement about what's in there.  It's more hit & miss with RSS.